# SonarQube 5.5 not compatible with Report Plugin 1.6

Tags: java, sonarqube

I just installed SonarQube 5.5 on my Linux server and I want to get PDF Reports exported, however when I tried to install "sonar-report-plugin-1.6.jar" from http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/ I get this error...

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Plugin 'report' is no more compatible with this version of SonarQube
```

Does anyone know of a PDF Export plugin that is compatible with SonarQube 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is another plugin is available. A look at the SonarQube [plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) version matrix confirms your findings. On the product [roadmap](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/REP/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:roadmap-panel) you can also see that there is no releasedate for version 1.7. Because this is a licensed product you could mail SonarSource for more background information.